# puppet basic configs

Tags: puppet

Im after basic puppet configs for common applications/setups but Im not having much luck finding any. I was wondering if anyone knew of any good resources for this sort of thing?

I was hoping to find PP files with just the bare basics to get something like nginx or mysql installed.

Something like : 
https://github.com/TracyWebTech/puppet-supervisor

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Puppet Forge](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/) for example modules to manage common applications - but keep in mind that those modules are largely community contributed; they might need some tweaking to fit your needs.